# Convert selected columns in csv to dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file called "archive". It is opened as a reader. I wish to create a dictionary whose values `(k,v)` are made from `{row[0]+row[2]:row[7]}` for each row in the csv file. There must be a simple straight forward way to turn this csv into a dictionary where `k = row[0]+row[2]` and `v = row[7]`.

```
# open archive reader
farchive = open ("wv5archive.csv","rb")
archive = csv.reader(farchive, delimiter=',')

for rows in archive: 
    arch_dict = {rows[0]+rows[2]:rows[7]} 

print arch_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use a dictionary comprehension:

```
arch_dict = {row[0]+row[2]: row[7] for row in archive}
```

If you're on an older version of Python:

```
arch_dict = {}
for row in archive: 
    arch_dict[row[0]+row[2]] = rows[7]
```

Comment: You could write the comprehension pre 2.7 as `dict( ((row[0],row[2]), row[7]) for row in archive)` - more elegant than your second option (or row[0]+row[2] - whatever)

Comment: "eye of the beholder"  I guess. Your answer (to me) just seems to imply that you have to create an empty dict, and iterate to assign key/vals if not using 2.7+ - and we agree that's not the case... Anyway, +1 from me.