# Convert a csv to a dictionary with multiple values?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file like this:

```
pos,place
6696,266835
6698,266835
938,176299
940,176299
941,176299
947,176299
948,176299
949,176299
950,176299
951,176299
770,272944
2751,190650
2752,190650
2753,190650
```

I want to convert it to a dictionary like the following:

```
{266835:[6696,6698],176299:[938,940,941,947,948,949,950,951],190650:[2751,2752,2753]}
```

And then, fill the missing numbers in the range in the values:

```
{{266835:[6696,6697,6698],176299:[938,939,940,941,942,943,944,945,946947,948,949,950,951],190650:[2751,2752,2753]}
}
```

Right now i have tried to build the dictionary using solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831216/convert-selected-columns-in-csv-to-dictionary), but it overwrites the old value with new one.

Any help would be great.

Here is a function that i wrote for converting csv2dict

```
def csv2dict(filename):
"""
reads in a two column csv file, and the converts it into dictionary
"""
import csv
with open(filename) as f:
    f.readline()#ignore first line
    reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
    mydict=dict((rows[1],rows[0]) for rows in reader)
return mydict
```

Comment: Look at [csv.DictReader](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader). I'd give an example but I've never used it myself so I'd be poring over the docs, too! It's certainly possible algorithmically, but I think `csv.DictReader` will do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: I have added a function that i wrote for converting cdv to dictionary..

Comment: What's with the second set of braces, or is that an error? As for the value fill-in, you could get the minimum and maximum of the endpoints and simply generate a range for each (disregarding the interstitial values).

Comment: second set of braces was added by the editor...not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest is to use [`collections.defaultdict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with a list:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

with open(inputfilename, 'rb') as infh:
    reader = csv.reader(infh)
    next(reader, None)  # skip the header

    for col1, col2 in reader:
        data[col2].append(int(col1))
        if len(data[col2]) > 1:
            data[col2] = range(min(data[col2]), max(data[col2]) + 1)
```

This also expands the ranges on the fly as you read the data.

Comment: What are the advantages of expanding the list to a range during read as opposed to running through each key once after it's read in?

Comment: @adsmith: not much of an advantage, really, but it  simplified the code here.

Comment: THANK YOU. it worked, i did have to change the last line to convert strings in the list to integer.
    
    data[col2]=range(min(map(int,data[col2])),max(map(int,data[col2]))+1)

Comment: @msakya: ah, of course. I altered a different line to turn `col1` into an integer instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters on the side note: Is it possible to expand only the selected range in the values. For example if values had [2,8,10,500,502], only expand it as [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,501,502] and not all numbers between 10 and 501. Basically use a threshold to expand.

Comment: @msakya: sure, with some more logic; but that'd be a separate question, I'd say.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks. actually posted the new question now :) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178771/how-to-expand-a-dictionary-value-of-integer-based-on-threshold)

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have tried -

```
from collections import default dict

# open archive reader
myFile = open ("myfile.csv","rb")
archive = csv.reader(myFile, delimiter=',')
arch_dict = defaultdict(list)

for rows in archive: 
    arch_dict[row[1]].append(row[0])

print arch_dict
```