# How to expand a list of integer based on a threshold?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, range

I have some lists of integers in python:

```
[[2, 8, 10, 500, 502], [1, 4, 5, 401]]
```

How would I expand the values into continuous ranges based on the difference between the numbers in the list so I get something like this:

```
[[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 500, 501, 502], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 401]]
```

So, basically, only expand a set of numbers into a full range if the difference between the items in the list is less than 100?

Comment: Are dictionaries essential for the problem? I think it's more like a problem of how to expand the list.

Comment: yes, I need to perform downstream analysis on these list based on the key.

Comment: @msakya: but for *this* question, the fact that your lists are values in a dictionary doesn't matter. I've edited your question for clarity and focus on the fact that these are lists.

Comment: because i am not interested in the range between 10 to 500, only the ones that are closer within a threshold, for example, 100 here.

Comment: @msakya: Any solution that works for these lists will work for your dictionary values too.

Comment: Are the lists always sorted beforehand?

Comment: @MartijnPieters didn't realize that, thanks for the modification.

Comment: what should the output be for input `[99, 0, 198]`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters can please you review my answer?

Comment: @zhangxaochen : since the difference is 99, that should fill the list from 0 to 99 to 198, if i were [100,0,200], it should just return [100,0,200]

Comment: Are there ever duplicates in the lists?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ugly, but try this:

```
def list_expand(x):
    new_list = []
    while True:
        if len(x) < 2:
            new_list.append(x[0])
            break

        m = min(x)
        x.remove(m)
        if abs(m - min(x)) < 100:
            new_list.extend(range(m, min(x)))
        else:
            new_list.append(m)
    return new_list
```

It passed these tests:

```
assert list_expand([99, 0, 198]) == range(0, 199)
assert list_expand([100, 0, 200]) == [0, 100, 200]
assert list_expand([2, 8, 10, 500, 502]) == range(2, 11) + range(500, 503)
assert list_expand([1, 4, 5, 401]) == range(1, 6) + [401]
```

Comment: You might want to look at `heapq` module.

Comment: @msakya Won't this fail for `[100, 0, 200, 150]`?

Comment: @thefourtheye What would be the best way to rewrite with `heapq`? I see the `min(x)/x.remove` could be replaced with `heappop(x)`, but is there more I can do with `heapq`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary This returns `[0] + range(100, 201)` for `[100, 0, 200, 150]`.

Comment: @Bill I thought OP's expected output for this should be `[100, 0, 150...200]`, let them clarify first.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary [100, 0, 200, 150] returned [0,100..200], which is what i want. Sorry if it were confusing

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary True. What is the expected output for a simpler case: `[198, 99, 0]`? Is it `[0...198]` or `[99...198, 0...98]`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version, might be shorter:

```
In [7]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [107]: def foo(l):
     ...:     l=sorted(l)
     ...:     t = l + [e for i, v in enumerate(l[1:]) for e in range(l[i], v) if v-l[i]<100]
     ...:     return list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(sorted(t)))

In [108]: assert foo([99, 0, 198]) == range(0, 199)
     ...: assert foo([100, 0, 200]) == [0, 100, 200]
     ...: assert foo([2, 8, 10, 500, 502]) == range(2, 11) + range(500, 503)
     ...: assert foo([1, 4, 5, 401]) == range(1, 6) + [401]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hacked away with `itertools.izip_longest` and the ternary alike operation :)

```
from itertools import izip_longest as zip

def list_expand(c):
   c = sorted(c)
   return [k for i,j in zip(c,c[1:],fillvalue=0) for k in [[i],range(i,j)][0<=j-i<100]]

assert list_expand([99, 0, 198]) == range(0, 199)
assert list_expand([100, 0, 200]) == [0, 100, 200]
assert list_expand([2, 8, 10, 500, 502]) == range(2, 11) + range(500, 503)
assert list_expand([1, 4, 5, 401]) == range(1, 6) + [401]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [2,8,10,500,502]

def expand_list(a):
    for element in a:
        if element < 10:
            for i in range(element):
                if i not in a:
                    a.append(i)
    return sorted(a)

print expand_list(a)
```

This is probably not the best solution, but I took this as a time challenge ;)

EDIT: This should pass the tests, although I am not sure if it is correct. But I think I am going to leave it at that.

```
a = [8, 2, 10, 500, 502]

def expand_list(a):
    a = sorted(a)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if i > 0:
            if (a[i] - a[i-1]) < 100:
                for j in range(a[i-1], a[i]):
                    if j not in a:
                        a.append(j)
    return sorted(a)
print expand_list(a)
```

Comment: this doesn't work for the latter part of list...for example it doesn't expand 500 and 502.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
v = [100, 0, 200]
v = sorted(v)
exp = []
for i, ele in enumerate(v[1:]):
    if ele - v[i] < 100:
        exp.extend(range(v[i], ele))
        exp.extend([ele]) # to add the last element of the range
if not exp:
    exp = v  # to take care of cases where the numbers in original list are all separated by > 100
else:
    exp = list(set(exp)) # to get rid of the duplicates had the input been [2, 8, 10, 11, 500, 502]
print exp
```

Comment: Wasn't aware unsorted lists were a possibility